# How to format and print on the same line in Python

Tags: python, string

So I have this list formatted as `<self.ID> - <neighbor>`:

```
1 - 2, 
1 - 3,    
2 - 1,    
2 - 4,    
3 - 1,   
3 - 4,    
4 - 2,    
4 - 3,
```

My goal is to have it output as such

```
1-2, 1-3    
2-1, 2-4    
3-1, 3-4    
4-2, 4-3
```

So basically put all of the same self.ID's on the same line and omit the comma after the last pair. Is there something in python that can do this, or does anyone know a fancy algorithm that can help? Thanks.

All I have right now is this:

```
for neighbor is self.list:
    print ""%d" % self.ID + " - " + "%d" % neighbor + ", "
```

This will obviously print line by line. I guess I'm just looking for a push in the right direction toward what i'm trying to do

UPDATE:

here is my new code:

```
array = []
for l in self.pairs
    string = "%d - %d" % (self.ID, l)
    array.append(string)
    print ", ".join(array)
```

and my new output:

```
1 - 2
1 - 2, 1 - 3
2 - 1
2 - 1, 2 - 4
3 - 1
4 - 2
```

I'm close. How do I stop it from repeating those pairs?

Comment: show the code you have done so far please

Comment: can we have more than 2 of "same self.ID's" ? Do the lines always go in sorted order?

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I don't have much. All I have is a loop that parses through a list of neighbors and prints it out line by line:

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm not sure how I can implement 2 of the same self.ID's, and yes, ideally they will always be sorted

Comment: Side note: you could simplify your print argument to `"%d - %d, " % (self.ID, neighbour)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda i: int(i.split('-')[0].strip())

values = groupby(sorted(your_list, key=key), key=key)

for _, l in values:
    print(', '.join(l))
```

How `group_by` works https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Adding some explanation into your answer would be nice. Especially for people who are new to itertools and groupby. What do they do?

Comment: This helped, but due to the nature of the assignment i'm trying not to import any additional libraries. I've updated my post with my current code

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear the inputs, but will share below code toget you started:

```
s = ['1', '-', '2,', '1', '-', '3,', '2', '-', '1,', '2', '-', '4,', '3', '-', '1,', '3', '-', '4,', '4', '-', '2,', '4', '-', '3,']
x = 0
y = 6
for _ in range(0, int(len(s)/6)):
    print(' '.join(s[x:y]))
    x+=6
    y+=6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i='0'
line =''
for item in list 
    item_s = item.split(' ')
    if (item_s[0] is i):
        line = line + item
    else:
        print(line)
        line=''
        i = item_s[0]
        line = line + item
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the zip operator? Not 100% sure whether this is the input you mean.

```
example = ["1-2,","1-3,","2-1,","2-4,", "3-1,","3-4,", "4-2,", "4-3,"]
result = [a + " " + b[:-1] for a,b in zip(example[0::2], example[1::2])]
result
```

where example[0::2] selects every second element starting from the index 0 and example[1::2] every second element starting at index 1
and b[:-1] gets rid of the ","

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

My goal was to have a list in the form `<self.ID> - <neighbor>, ...`

My original code with output:

```
for neighbor is self.list:
    print ""%d" % self.ID + " - " + "%d" % neighbor + ", "

1 - 2, 
1 - 3,    
2 - 1,    
2 - 4,    
3 - 1,   
3 - 4,    
4 - 2,    
4 - 3,
```

My final code with output:

```
array = []
for l in self.pairs
    string = "%d - %d" % (self.ID, l)
array.append(string)
print ", ".join(array)


1-2, 1-3    
2-1, 2-4    
3-1, 3-4    
4-2, 4-3
```

Thanks everyone for your help.